# The properties of implementation model in UML

Tags: uml, implementation, modeling, artifacts

In the `UML reference manual` `page 18`

Full specifications of a final system:

An implementation model includes enough information to build the system. It must include not only the logical semantics of the system and the algorithms, data structures, and mechanisms that ensure proper performance, `but also organizational decisions about the system artifacts
that are necessary for cooperative work by humans and processing by tools`

What the highlighted sentence means?

Answer (score 1):

It basically means that with UML modeling, you can go far beyond describing algorithms. You can (and should) put the technical information in context and describe what the system you describe is good for, how it will be used, for what purpose and by whom.

Comment: thank you @observer for your kind answer.Could you please provide a simple UML implementation model as example that support your clarification(I would like to imagine that)?

Comment: The quotation describes a rather low-level concept of models in general. When applied to UML (which of course is the purpose of the document), there are many different ways of making a UML model work for both human stakeholders and machines. This is expressed in the different views as can be seen in table 3.1.

Comment: Thank you dude for your kind help 
I saw the table but I would like to show me a `UML Example` . I made a comprehensive search for example in UML that is fully elaborated but I didn't find. I only noticed a very general examples Do you think so(By your experience)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because it's an obscure usage, you might be wondering about the use of the word "artifacts" here. In this context, it refers to any of the persisted entities in your design, which can include databases, files, archives, cloud-storage, tapes, printouts, etc. Basically any component in the system that has a lifetime or can serve as long-term memory.